# AngularJS get the current culture Date Format

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, date-format

I use

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/angular.min.js
https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.5/i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js
```

I need to obtain the current

```
DATETIME_FORMATS.shortDate
```

say

```
<input type="date" name="fromdate" id="fromdate"
       placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" ng-model="fromDate" />
```

something like this?

```
<input type="date" name="fromdate" id="fromdate"
       placeholder="{{$locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.shortDate}}" ng-model="fromDate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside controller, inject $locale service & have scope variable to set the date format:

```
$scope.localDateFormat = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS;
```

And in view as :

```
<input type="text" name="fromdate" id="fromdate"
       placeholder="{{localDateFormat.shortDate}}" ng-model="fromDate" />
```

Again this will work only if you're having `type='text'` it'll fail for `type='date'` as date type is handled natively in all browsers. It's not even supported by Firefox & IE11. So better way is to have just text field & some generic datepicker library like ui-bootstrap or angular material datepickers which have support for all the browsers. In [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) they've not provided placeholder in usage if input type is `date` (for non-supporting browsers you can have the placeholder it says).

(It still can be achieved by using type as date but by unusual DOM manipulation like having text field & onfocus turning it into date & onblur back to text, just to show user defined placeholder)

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NkhdgKc3MEAObqhrTud7?p=preview)